# How to replace a word in multiple lines using sed?

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to edit a CSV file like this:

```
1:field1,field2,field3,FIELD I WANT TO REPLACE, fieldx ...
2:field1,field2,field3,FIELD I WANT TO REPLACE, fieldx ...
3:field1,field2,field3,FIELD I WANT TO REPLACE, fieldx ...
5:field1,field2,field3,FIELD I WANT TO REPLACE, fieldx ...
```

Can I use `sed` to replace searching for the pattern `FIELD I WANT TO REPLACE` and switching for something like :

```
1:field1,field2,field3,NEW FIELD, fieldx ...
2:field1,field2,field3,NEW FIELD, fieldx ...
3:field1,field2,field3,NEW FIELD, fieldx ...
5:field1,field2,field3,NEW FIELD, fieldx ...
```

Comment: Are all the lines the same except the initial field?  If not where are the matched and replaced values?

Comment: The question is if the value in second line is different from value in first field, how you want to match them and replace it with values?  Perhaps you want to change column 4 in a csv file?

Comment: hostname,clientname,ID TAG,OS,location,comment,Service desk procedure1,field
hostname,clientname,ID TAG,OS,location,comment,Service desk procedure1,field
hostname,clientname,ID TAG,OS,location,comment,Service desk procedure1,field


and i want to change to 


hostname,clientname,ID TAG,OS,location,comment,Service desk procedure2,field
hostname,clientname,ID TAG,OS,location,comment,Service desk procedure2,field
hostname,clientname,ID TAG,OS,location,comment,Service desk procedure2,field

i usually use atom or notepad ++ to do that, but since its over 20k plus lines, the app crashes.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you trying to replace the text `FIELD I WANT TO REPLACE` wherever it occurs or are you trying to replace whatever text is in the 4th field?

Comment: i think both ways would work, but im more interested in replacing a pattern rather than a field

Comment: OK but then you run into issues related to what you mean by a "pattern". Is it a regexp or a string (never actually use the word "pattern" in this context as it has too many possible meanings)? Should partial matches be allowed or not? Is it case sensitive or not? Should only the first or all occurrences be replaced? When replacing a field by it's position you have none of those concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you wanting just a simple find and replace?  If so, try something like this:

```
sed -e 's/FIELD I WANT TO REPLACE/NEW FIELD/' input_file >output_file
```

If you ware looking for something more, please explain further.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest is using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

Lets say you want to replace field 5

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$5="SOME NEW TEXT"}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

based on the comment you're trying to do

```
$ sed -i.bak 's/,Service desk procedure1,/,Service desk procedure2,/' file
```

commas are there to eliminate accidental matches if the searched string exists as a substring somewhere else.  Also not setting `g` flag, we are restricting to one match per line.

This will do inplace replacement and the old version will be renamed with `.bak` suffix.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider a proper CSV parser. For example, ruby comes with one:

```
ruby -rcsv -e '
  f = ARGV.shift
  # read the data
  data = CSV.read(f)
  # make your updates
  data.each {|row| row[6]="Service desk procedure2"}
  # write back to the file
  CSV.open(f, "w") {|csv| data.each {|row| csv << row}}
' file
```

or the perl-ish one-liner (although I understand the ruby community frowns at such)

```
ruby -rcsv -i.bak -ne 'CSV.parse($_) {|row| row[6]="foo"; puts CSV.generate_line(row)}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^,]*/NEW FIELD/4' file
```

Replace the 4th occurrence of zero or more non-comma characters by the literal `NEW FIELD`.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I expect more elegant solutions out there (probably awk):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "1:field1,field2,field3,FIELD I WANTawef TO REPfLACE, fieldx ..." > data.txt
echo "1:field1,field2,field3,FIELD I wefaaWANT TO REPLACE, fieldx ..." >> data.txt
echo "1:field1,field2,field3,FIELD I WANT TO REPawefL ACE, fieldx ..." >> data.txt
echo "1:field1,field2,field3,FIEawefLDa I WANT TO REPLACE, fieldx ..." >> data.txt

sed -e 's/\(.:.*,.*,.*\),.*,\(.*\)/\1,NEW FIELD,\2/' data.txt
```

So my `sed` matches:

- **`.:`** 1 character followed by :
- **`.*,.*,.*`**: 3 columns
- **`,.*,`**: the 4th column.  I decided to include the commas in the forth column, makes it clearer to read
- **`.*`**: everything that follows the 4th column
- **`\1,NEW FIELD,\2`**: put everything before the 4th column, the new field, and everything following the 4th column.

This way there is no matching any content, this way it always works, as long as you respect the columns separated by ','.